# How do I get the coordinates of the IOS device using RubyMotion?

Tags: rubymotion

Just looking for the simplest example of extracting the gps coordinates - not looking to render them on a map or anything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS 8, do the following:

1. Add these lines to your Rakefile:

   ```
   app.frameworks += ['CoreLocation']
   app.info_plist['NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription'] = 'I need it'
   app.info_plist['NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription'] = 'I always need it'
   ```
2. In `viewDidLoad` in your `ViewController` add:

   ```
   @locationManager = CLLocationManager.alloc.init
   @locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization
   @locationManager.delegate = self
   @locationManager.startUpdatingLocation
   ```
3. Implement `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

   ```
   def locationManager(manager, didUpdateLocations:locations)
     coordinate = locations[0].coordinate
     puts "lat #{coordinate.latitude}, long #{coordinate.longitude}"
   end
   ```
4. If you need just the current location once, then call:

   ```
   manager.stopUpdatingLocation
   ```

   after getting the location in `didUpdateLocations`.